# Force HTTPS on certain URLs and force HTTP for all others

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, https

I have a client project where I need to force HTTPS for a certain folder and force HTTP for all others. I can sucessfully enforce HTTPS for the folder I desire but then all links back to the rest of the site end up being through HTTPS. I'd like to have a rule which forces requests for anything 'not' in the secure folder to be forced back to HTTP. Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(my) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
```

'my' is the name of the folder that I need to force HTTPS for.

Any ideas?

Update: I also tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]

# Force HTTPS for /my
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(my) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

# Force HTTP for anything which isn't /my
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule !^my http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

# Remove index.php from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
```

But instead of requests for /my being forced through HTTPS they now just resolve to http://www.example.com/index.php/my

:?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ah, of course. The problem lies in the fact that your rewrite ruleset will be reprocessed after it is transformed to `index.php` following the initial redirect. Using what you currently have, you need to additionally condition the redirections to make sure they don't get applied after the rewrite to `/index.php/my`.

Something like the following should do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]

# Force HTTPS for /my
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/my [NC]
RewriteRule ^(my) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

# Force HTTP for anything which isn't /my
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\s/my [NC]
RewriteRule !^my http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

# Remove index.php from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
```

Comment: Thanks , saved me a lot of time!  FWIW, in Wordpress, the basic Wordpress htaccess IfModule already removes index.php from URLs.

Answer (score 4):

Give the following a try, should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is something that works from an old client website and could be adaptable for your purposes:

```
#If https off and in the cart dir
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cart/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/cart/%1 [R=301,L]

#If https on and not in cart dir    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cart [NC]
#Above line actually used to read RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cart|media|images|thumbs|css|js [NC]
#to allow js/css/images to be served so there were no mixed ssl messages popping up to visitors
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Replacing cart with my perhaps

Answer (score 0):

Just invert the conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule !^my http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi ya, thanks for the speedy reply. I tried that but I wasn't sure where to place it in the flow of my existing rules, any pointers? If I place it above the existing 'Force HTTPS' rule it prevents the 'Force HTTPS' from working and also prevents the final rule which rewrites index.php from executing. :?

Comment: @Nathan Pitman: No, since they have different matching conditions they should not interact.

Comment: ok, I tried what you suggested (see the update to my original post) but this didn't work. I can see that it 'should' but I think I perhaps have the rules in the wrong order or certain rules are causing the rewrite to terminate before other conditions and rules can be evaluated... :/

Comment: @Nathan Pitman: Or you didn't mention that you're defining the rules in `httpd.conf` (or similar) and everyone assumed it was in `.htaccess`, in which case you need to make sure all the test patterns match `^/`, e.g. `^/my` (I might be wrong though, it was just a thought)

Comment: Hi Tim, yea this is being defined in .htaccess