# Programatically forcing https on MAMP Pro for specific pages (not site wide and without using .htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, ssl-certificate, mamp, mamp-pro

Is there a way of setting MAMP Pro up to use SSL for specific pages of a CMS site rather than a global site-wide enforcing of SSL.

A SilverStripe site we are working on requires only portions of the site to be secure and so we programmatically enforce this using `Director::forceSSL` on the specific areas of the site.  It works well on the live production site - real host / domain.

When I enable SSL in MAMP Pro on our dev machine it is applied site-wide and I can only access the site with https://mysite.local:8890/.  In other words is there a way of having the self-signed certificate in MAMP Pro installed but not used unless (programatically) enforced, without touching the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear this is not possible. Your options might be:

- htaccess
- CMS

**htaccess**
[Force HTTPS on certain sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307025/force-https-on-certain-urls-and-force-http-for-all-others):

```
# Force HTTPS for /my
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/my [NC]
RewriteRule ^(my) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

**CMS**
Force HTTPS on certain pages with your CMS.
In your case [this could help](http://www.silverstripe.org/general-questions/show/16896).

Comment: After some weeks of trying to achieve this I came to the same conclusion.  I came to accept that I had to live with https for the whole site in my dev environment.  All worked fine the production server (using SilverStripe's forceSSL() for the relevant pages / areas)