# restricting http to https redirect for the url containing arduino text

Tags: json, apache, server, server-configuration

I have HTTP to HTTPS redirect configured in server, to display json data coming from arduino MCU on port 8090 I need to restrict  http to https redirect, so following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3313636/3311276) I have configured my apache web server to below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      RewriteEngine on
      ServerName     192.168.1.45

      # force ssl
      RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
      RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

      # force HTTP for /arduino
      RewriteCond    %{HTTPS} =on
      RewriteRule    ^(arduino) http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

</VirtualHost>
```

then I restarted apache server and refreshed the page but I am still getting the error in browser console saying:

> [Warning] [blocked] The page at
>   https://www.example.com/arduino/gauge.htm was not allowed to display
>   insecure content from http://www.example.com:8090/json. (jquery.min.js,
>   line 5)

I have even tried :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      RewriteEngine on
      ServerName     192.168.1.45

      # force ssl
      RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
      RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

      # force HTTP for /json
      RewriteCond    %(SERVER_PORT} ^8090
      RewriteCond    %{HTTPS} =on
      RewriteRule    ^(json) http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

</VirtualHost>
```

but it doesnt work. same error in console, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue is in the browser (client) not in your server config. For security reasons most of modern browser blocks all http requests when you get a page from https domain, in your case: https://san.gotdns.ch/arduino/gauge.htm

In MDN:

> Starting with Firefox 23, Firefox blocks active mixed content by default. This follows a practice adopted by Internet Explorer (since version 9) and Chrome.

Maybe this article could be useful for you:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content

The interesting part:

> How to fix your website
>
> The best strategy to avoid mixed content blocking is to serve all the
>   content as HTTPS instead of HTTP.
>
> For your own domain, serve all content as HTTPS and fix your links. 
>   Often, the HTTPS version of the content already exists and this just
>   requires adding an "s" to links - http:// to https://.
>
> However, in some cases, the path may just be incorrect to the media in
>   question. There are online as well as offline tools (depending on your
>   operating system) such as linkchecker to help resolve this.
>
> For other domains, use the site's HTTPS version if available. If HTTPS
>   is not available, you can try contacting the domain and asking them if
>   they can make the content available via HTTPS.

Comment: Well in that case what should I do ?

Comment: I think If can completely skip redirection to https I won't fall into this pit

Comment: The json is coming from micro controller that cannot deliver https

Comment: Take a view this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire

Comment: Also this question could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http#8380

Comment: so according to most voted answer as per your link If json is pulled from server on different port in my case would it become `src=//:8090/json` ?